# Help in solving linear differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The equation is:

$(xy^4 + y)dx -xdy =0$

I brought the differential terms to the same side and then divided by $y^2$ to get this.

$(xy^2)dy=d(y/x)$.

I tried an alternate way to simplify it which got me this:

$d(x/y) +xydx=0$

I got stuck here. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Try $y=ux$ and see what the DE for $u$ in terms of $x$ is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write it as
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac1x\,y+y^4\quad\text{or}\quad y^{-4}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac1x\,y^{-3}+1.
$$
This is a Bernoulli equation. The change $z=y^{-3}$ will transform it into a linear equation.